# How to create a web scraper in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrap data of Airtel stores across India. Location of all the stores is available here on their website: https://www.airtel.in/store

I am absolutely new to this. I tried following selenium tutorials for Python and came up with this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "E:\Ballance\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://airtel.in/store")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("autocomplete")
inputElement.send_keys('Lajput Nagar')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs-14")
driver.close()
```

This to scrap data of all the stores in "Lajput Nagar" locality.

However, it is throwing failed to save user data error

```
$[8704:17660:0612/132447.282:ERROR:entry_impl.cc(962)] Failed to save user data
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: first of all `https://airtel.in/store` doesn't exists and redirects to hompage

Comment: it exist i just checked

Comment: If you want, you can check out BeautifulSoup for web scrapping with python. It's commonly used.

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis It's possible that the website is Region-based, and users outside of India may see a different page. I personally cannot see it.

Comment: link is working

Comment: you can find elements by driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id='scroll_container']') and then loop to individual address div